# How do I find the point between two point at a specific distance (in x,y coordinates)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am working on a programming project and have run into a problem.

I need to find a point that is on a line. For example if my line is AC and I have the coordinates for point A and C, how can I get the coordinates for B on the same line between A and C.  B will be a set distance from A, for example 60.

So if the coords for point A are (20,45) and the coords for point C are (120, 240), how do I get the x,y coords for point B that is a distance of 60 from point A.

I hope that made sense.

It has been a long time since math class, so please keep it as simple as possible.

This is not homework, it is just a problem that has been bugging me for hours.

Comment: Is this homework ? Feels like it

Comment: Actually, it is not. I am trying to develop a game and I need to draw a line from a starting point to point that is 60 away from that point. the line AC is the line from my starting point to the x,y of the mouse cursor. I can draw a line from the starting point to the cursor, but that is not what I need. The x,y coord I gave are just a random example

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=(a,b)$ and $C=(c,d)$. The points on the line $AC$ have coordinates $(x_t,y_t)$ where 
$$x_t=(1-t)a+tc,\qquad y_t=(1-t)b+td,$$
where $t$ ranges over the reals. (For the line segment $[A,B]$, the parameter $t$ ranges over the interval $[0,1]$.)

for positive $t$, the distance from  $A$ to $(x_t,y_t)$ is $t$ times the distance from $A$ to $C$. So for your problem, calculate the distance $d$ from $A$ to $C$, and let $t=\frac{60}{d}$.

In your example, $d=\sqrt{(120-20)^2+(240-45)^2}\approx  219.146$.

Comment: thank you, I think this is what I need. I will go put it into code and let you know.

Comment: Note that the formula works for all non-negative $t$. (Numbers $t\gt 1$ give us points beyond $C$.) *Negative* $t$ give us points on the line, but in the direction opposite to the direction $C$ is. In that case, we need $t$ *negative*, with absolute value distance from $A$ divided by $d$. If you want to look things up, I am using the **parametric equation** of the line.

Comment: thanks again.  It's working!

Comment: Great! If I were doing it, it would not work so quickly, write code, $10$ minutes, debug, hours.

Comment: Just thought you might like to see the finished c# code
inline
`double nLineLength = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x -objLine.StartPoint.X, 2) + Math.Pow(y - objLine.StartPoint.Y, 2));
float nMaxLength = 60;

                if (nLineLength > nMaxLength)
                {
                    float t = nMaxLength / (float)nLineLength;
                    float xt = (1 - t) * (float)objLine.StartPoint.X + (t * x);
                    float yt = (1 - t) * (float)objLine.StartPoint.Y + (t * y);

                    objLine.EndPoint = new Point(xt, yt);`

Comment: Am pleased to have an answer turn into something real.

Answer (score 1):

Write the equation of a line 
Say A=(a,b) and C=(c,d) then equation of line is (y-d)(c-a)=(d-b)(x-c) now you know the distance of B from A and equation of line AC.
let B=(k,l)so you have two equations 
1. Point B lies on line AC i.e. it satisfies equation of line AC
2.and also we know that the distance between AB=squart[(a^2-k^2)+(b^2-l^2)]

so two equations and two unknowns
you get coordinates of point B